How do I fix this cors error when attempting to host on vercel
I am trying to deploy and host my app on vercel. I have checked my development server and my app works perfectly fine however on vercel I get :
about:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portfolio-beryl-eight-48.vercel.app/api/github/fetch-profile' from origin 'https://ckolaportfolio.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
const config = require('./utils/config')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
const githubRouter = require('./controllers/github')


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('dist'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(middleware.requestLogger)

app.use('/api/github', githubRouter)


app.use(middleware.unknownEndpoint)
app.use(middleware.errorHandler)

module.exports = app

I have included cors as seen above and I still do not understand why it is failing I have also included this vercel.json in my backend
directory
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "index.js"
        }
    ],
    "headers": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                    "value": "https://ckolaportfolio.vercel.app"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "value": "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "value": "Content-Type, Authorization"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

what could I possibly be missing? I have included environment keys in my backend on vercel.
require('dotenv').config()

const PORT = process.env.PORT
const GITHUB_TOKEN = process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN
const ALLOWED_ORIGINS = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(',').map(origin => origin.trim())
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const FRONTEND_URL = process.env.FRONTEND_URL || 'https://ckolaportfolio.vercel.app'

module.exports = {
    PORT,
    GITHUB_TOKEN,
    ALLOWED_ORIGINS,
    NODE_ENV,
    FRONTEND_URL
}

that is my config.js above


Share the exact request being made, then find the OPTIONS request in the network tab and share the HTTP response headers that came back from the server for the request that failed.

@Evert I have added a screenshot of my request please take a look

I got the same error around 6 months ago, it was happening because i was hosting both the backend and the frontend on the same server and here is how i fixed it:
Here is the vercel config file for the frontend:
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source":"/(.*)",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

and the config file for the backend:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js"
    }
  ]
}

Note that i needed to host on different servers (bold so you don't miss it). I tried playing with CORS but it turned out not to be the cause of the problem. I suppose that you tried to find on the internet but couldn't find anything (as i did during days for this problem ; )).
I don't really know if it fits your project but i let you adapt because you must understand how it will fit your project better than me. If i misunderstood something about what you said, feel free to let me know, i would be glad to help.
